# Creating hidden OS with linux

Tags: linux, encryption

I know that truecrypt isn't capable of creating a hidden OS but in [another post](https://superuser.com/a/1084494) someone describes the steps to do it manually and that he does it to all of his linux computers all of the time. Can anyone elaborate on his steps so that someone (like myself) who is not as experienced could accomplish this?

I would just ask this individual to provide more details but it appears as though their account is "anonymous" or something.

Comment: Ask it as a comment to the original answer (on Superuser, not here). And the user name is just that, a name. If that users is still active, you could still try and message them, by use of a comment to that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I developed something like you are describing.

Here https://github.com/antonio-petricca/buddy-linux you can find all the information and installation script.

**Buddy linux** allows you to install linux on (hidden) loop files (like for the link you provided), but providing GRUB loader by an external USB drive. So, removing, it will results in a Windows boot.

The other good stuff is that it is based on LVM, so you can extended file system "simply" by adding loop files as per your needs.

Regards.

Comment: I got a popup asking about installing kubuntu, but during installation it says that no root file system is defined. What should I do?

Comment: Please open an issue on github providing detailed information and screenshots (if needed). Thank you